# Can't get sprite to rotate correctly?

Tags: java, sprites, rotation, movement, slick

I'm attempting to play with graphics using Java/Slick 2d. I'm trying to get my sprite to rotate to wherever the mouse is on the screen and then move accordingly. I figured the best way to do this was to keep track of the angle the sprite is at since I have to multiply the cosine/sine of the angle by the move speed in order to get the sprite to go "forwards" even if it is, say, facing 45 degrees in quadrant 3. However, before I even worry about that, I'm having trouble even getting my sprite to rotate in the first place. Preliminary console tests showed that this code worked, but when applied to the sprite, it just kind twitches. Anyone know what's wrong?

```
int mX = Mouse.getX();
    int mY = HEIGHT - Mouse.getY();
    int pX = sprite.x;
    int pY = sprite.y;
    int tempY, tempX;
    double mAng, pAng = sprite.angle;
    double angRotate=0;

    if(mX!=pX){
        tempY=pY-mY;
        tempX=mX-pX;

        mAng = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(Math.abs((tempY)),Math.abs((tempX))));
        if(mAng==0 && mX<=pX)
            mAng=180;
    }
    else{
        if(mY>pY)
            mAng=270;
        else
            mAng=90;
    }

    //Calculations
    if(mX<pX&&mY<pY){ //If in Q2
        mAng = 180-mAng;
    }
    if(mX<pX&&mY>pY){ //If in Q3
        mAng = 180+mAng;
    }
    if(mX>pX&&mY>pY){ //If in Q4
        mAng = 360-mAng;
    }

    angRotate = mAng-pAng;
    sprite.angle = mAng;

    sprite.image.setRotation((float)angRotate);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your last statements, you're calculating the angle difference then calling setRotation.

```
angRotate = mAng-pAng;
sprite.angle = mAng;

sprite.image.setRotation((float)angRotate);
```

`setRotation` as the name indicates: **Sets** the rotation. You should replace the above with:

```
sprite.angle = mAng;

sprite.image.setRotation((float)sprite.angle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is actually causing your issue, but you shouldn't have to `abs` the arguments of `atan2`. That will also get rid of most of the rest of this code as well.